# Is it possible to combine Desktop Testing and Web Testing in single Test case

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, appium-desktop

We need to perform some click and input actions in desktop application and immediately checking those details in web applications. Is it possible to use separate drivers for each application in same test cases?

Appium supports windows mobile and web. Is it possible to do with appium in single driver swaps? Kindly share the approaches, feasibility and your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using just on driver. I already worked in an application using Appium and performed different tests, one directly on GUI (WinForm) and another tests directly on database.
I know that is not exactly what you need, but to do it you will just need at your tests stack to have two instances one for desktop and another for web test.
On your tests stack have two groups one for web and another for desktop to be more easy and separate your tests for different platforms.
PS: I suggest to initialize always both instances (desktop and web) whatever it is the platform you are testing.